# math mode print as normal mode when a command is fragile

Tags: macros, definition

i have created a macro, when the command in math mode print in bold, if it is outside math it should print in color

```
\def\mathtest{\ifmmode ***math mode***\else\textcolor{red}{***text mode***}\fi}
```

when using the command in section Head,  the output is printing correctly in section head alone but in the running head (when a macro is fragile), it is print as a normal mode

```
\section{Section Head $\mathtest$}
```

How to get the Running head same like in head. without using `\protect`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{RED}{rgb}{1,0,0}    
\begin{document}


\def\mathtest{\ifmmode ***math mode***\else\textcolor{red}{***text mode***}\fi}


\chapter{Sample Chapter}

\section{Section Head $\mathtest$}

As conservation geneticists, we recognize the importance of genetic diversity in maintaining healthy
natural populations, and in facilitating adaptation to new environmental conditions and challenges. However, both population
genetics and the American conservation movement have their roots in the human eugenics movement of a century ago,
which viewed genetic diversity among human populations as grounds for discrimination and prejudice. We acknowledge this
unfortunate part of the history of both population genetics and conservation, and denounce how it has been used to suppress
and disadvantage people.

Many of the early statistical methods that still underlie genetic analysis were developed by devout eugenicists. Francis
Galton, a cousin of Charles Darwin, coined the term eugenics in 1883 (Galton 1883, p. 24). Simply put, the field of eugenics
viewed human traits as the product of genes, some trait variants more valuable than others, and therefore some human races
as better than others (Rohlfs 2020). Galton also developed the concept of linear regression analysis, initially termed “reversion
to the mean” or “reversion to mediocrity,” which remains widely used in analysis of data of many types. Ronald A. Fisher,
who was one of the founders of population genetics, and who developed the statistical method analysis of variance, was also
a staunch eugenicist. Much of The Genetical Theory of Natural Selection (Fisher 1930) was devoted to Fisher’s concern with
the genetic effects of the lower fertility of the English upper class. US President Theodore Roosevelt and his conservation chief
Gifford Pinchot, considered fathers of the conservation movement in their country, were both part of the eugenics movement
(Wohlforth2010).
to eugenics.

Many of the early statistical methods that still underlie genetic analysis were developed by devout eugenicists. Francis
Galton, a cousin of Charles Darwin, coined the term eugenics in 1883 (Galton 1883, p. 24). Simply put, the field of eugenics
viewed human traits as the product of genes, some trait variants more valuable than others, and therefore some human races
as better than others (Rohlfs 2020). Galton also developed the concept of linear regression analysis, initially termed “reversion
to the mean” or “reversion to mediocrity,” which remains widely used in analysis of data of many types. Ronald A. Fisher,
who was one of the founders of population genetics, and who developed the statistical method analysis of variance, was also
a staunch eugenicist. Much of The Genetical Theory of Natural Selection (Fisher 1930) was devoted to Fisher’s concern with
the genetic effects of the lower fertility of the English upper class. US President Theodore Roosevelt and his conservation chief
Gifford Pinchot, considered fathers of the conservation movement in their country, were both part of the eugenics movement
(Wohlforth2010).
to eugenics.


Many of the early statistical methods that still underlie genetic analysis were developed by devout eugenicists. Francis
Galton, a cousin of Charles Darwin, coined the term eugenics in 1883 (Galton 1883, p. 24). Simply put, the field of eugenics
viewed human traits as the product of genes, some trait variants more valuable than others, and therefore some human races
as better than others (Rohlfs 2020). Galton also developed the concept of linear regression analysis, initially termed “reversion
to the mean” or “reversion to mediocrity,” which remains widely used in analysis of data of many types. Ronald A. Fisher,
who was one of the founders of population genetics, and who developed the statistical method analysis of variance, was also
a staunch eugenicist. Much of The Genetical Theory of Natural Selection (Fisher 1930) was devoted to Fisher’s concern with
the genetic effects of the lower fertility of the English upper class. US President Theodore Roosevelt and his conservation chief
Gifford Pinchot, considered fathers of the conservation movement in their country, were both part of the eugenics movement
(Wohlforth2010).
to eugenics.

Many of the early statistical methods that still underlie genetic analysis were developed by devout eugenicists. Francis
Galton, a cousin of Charles Darwin, coined the term eugenics in 1883 (Galton 1883, p. 24). Simply put, the field of eugenics
viewed human traits as the product of genes, some trait variants more valuable than others, and therefore some human races
as better than others (Rohlfs 2020). Galton also developed the concept of linear regression analysis, initially termed “reversion
to the mean” or “reversion to mediocrity,” which remains widely used in analysis of data of many types. Ronald A. Fisher,
who was one of the founders of population genetics, and who developed the statistical method analysis of variance, was also
a staunch eugenicist. Much of The Genetical Theory of Natural Selection (Fisher 1930) was devoted to Fisher’s concern with
the genetic effects of the lower fertility of the English upper class. US President Theodore Roosevelt and his conservation chief
Gifford Pinchot, considered fathers of the conservation movement in their country, were both part of the eugenics movement
(Wohlforth2010).
to eugenics.


Many of the early statistical methods that still underlie genetic analysis were developed by devout eugenicists. Francis
Galton, a cousin of Charles Darwin, coined the term eugenics in 1883 (Galton 1883, p. 24). Simply put, the field of eugenics
viewed human traits as the product of genes, some trait variants more valuable than others, and therefore some human races
as better than others (Rohlfs 2020). Galton also developed the concept of linear regression analysis, initially termed “reversion
to the mean” or “reversion to mediocrity,” which remains widely used in analysis of data of many types. Ronald A. Fisher,
who was one of the founders of population genetics, and who developed the statistical method analysis of variance, was also
a staunch eugenicist. Much of The Genetical Theory of Natural Selection (Fisher 1930) was devoted to Fisher’s concern with
the genetic effects of the lower fertility of the English upper class. US President Theodore Roosevelt and his conservation chief
Gifford Pinchot, considered fathers of the conservation movement in their country, were both part of the eugenics movement
(Wohlforth2010).
to eugenics.

Many of the early statistical methods that still underlie genetic analysis were developed by devout eugenicists. Francis
Galton, a cousin of Charles Darwin, coined the term eugenics in 1883 (Galton 1883, p. 24). Simply put, the field of eugenics
viewed human traits as the product of genes, some trait variants more valuable than others, and therefore some human races
as better than others (Rohlfs 2020). Galton also developed the concept of linear regression analysis, initially termed “reversion
to the mean” or “reversion to mediocrity,” which remains widely used in analysis of data of many types. Ronald A. Fisher,
who was one of the founders of population genetics, and who developed the statistical method analysis of variance, was also
a staunch eugenicist. Much of The Genetical Theory of Natural Selection (Fisher 1930) was devoted to Fisher’s concern with
the genetic effects of the lower fertility of the English upper class. US President Theodore Roosevelt and his conservation chief
Gifford Pinchot, considered fathers of the conservation movement in their country, were both part of the eugenics movement
(Wohlforth2010).
to eugenics.


\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a robust definition:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\mathtest}{}{%
  \ifmmode
    % math
  \else
    % not math
  \fi
}
```

Alternatively, [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) provides a way to make the command robust:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\mathtest
```